# Git Version Large Sensitive Files but Only Locally

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I am looking to add version control to large sensitive data files which I have placed in the .gitignore file. Ex. My repository is structured like:

```
project/
    script1.py
    script2.py
    data/
        sensitive_large1.txt
        sensitive_large2.txt
```

With a .gitignore file:

```
data/
```

However, I still want to be able to version these sensitive files locally to track the changes made on them. I looked into git submodules but am not certain if this solves my problem. If I ran `git init submodule` inside the data directory would that be sufficient to track those files locally, or is there a better solution?

Comment: why do you want to Version These files only locally? Is size the only matter (then other solutions like git-lfs might be considered) or for data security?

Comment: Essentially the data files are my outputs, which should not be pushed for data security purposes. But I would still like to know how my output has changed over time as I have been updating my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to (and probably you shouldn't) use submodules for this. But you can init new git repository in `data` directory. So you finally will have 2 repositories, not connected with each other:

1. Main repository in root of your project with everything except `data` directory (it should be ignored in `gitignore`).
2. Private repository in `data` directory with all sensitive data.

You're pushing to remote only changes from first repository, and second repository is only local.